# onclicking menu it hangs for some time and then goes to secondview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have made application where I have menu. On clicking menu button, it will go to respective view controller.

Today I added newviewcontroller where I have data coming from online server and I am showing that data in UITableView.

But what **weird happening is** when I click on button, it hangs for some time (in this hang time it fetches all the data for newviewcontroller) and then come on newviewcontroller.

**Note:** For fetching data, I have all code in newviewcontroller.

Any idea why this is happening?

---

For fetching the data, I have code which is exactly same as in below link.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/

for going from first view controller to newviewcontroller, below is code I have.

```
DoctorsListViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"doctorsen"];
secondView.myMainURL = @"my url here";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

---

Below is what I have in my viewDidLoad of newviewcontroller (doctorlistviewcontroller)

```
startNumberLabel.text = @"0";
typeNumber = @"0";

feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *myTMainURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?type=%@&index=%@", myMainURL, typeNumber, startNumberLabel.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myTMainURL];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code for fetching the data?

Comment: Which method in the newViewController fetches the data?

Comment: Can you post the code for your viewDidLoad of DoctorsListViewController

Comment: @sbarow : updated question with the same..

Comment: Can you move this parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; to a different method. after viewDidLoad is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Example in the link

```
    startNumberLabel.text = @"0";
typeNumber = @"0";

feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *myTMainURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?type=%@&index=%@", myMainURL, typeNumber, startNumberLabel.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myTMainURL];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[parser parse];
```

you have the data that is loaded synchronously that's the reason the the viewController takes time to load and after it has loaded all the data it is loaded and displayed.

**So, you can download all the data asynchronously or in a thread and then after the data is downloaded and parsed; Update the View or reload the tableView(if using)**

[Here is the link to Download data Asynchronously](http://codeshape.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/creating-an-asynchronous-xml-parser-for-ios-applications/)

after you have done that Implement one of the following

1) [Apple's reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

2) [Tony Millio's Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

and check network status then host status(So that you can display proper message etc) and then call the URL.

Comment: This is correct, your view will only be pushed once the download has completed with a slow internet connection this could take a while. Have a look at this tutorial http://codeshape.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/creating-an-asynchronous-xml-parser-for-ios-applications/ to see how to download on a background thread.

Comment: ohh... what changes need I need to do for asynchronous download?

Comment: as @sbarow mentioned the link please check it out